# Uploading String to mySQL | syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, upload

I am trying to connect to my mySQL database using java. I seem to be able to connect but am unable to use stmt.executeUpdate to upload to the database. The token I am trying to upload is a string but I get this in my console:

1b7a19bb5d924bc5b13d53c7b2a47394
Connected
*com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1b7a19bb5d924bc5b13d53c7b2a47394' at line 1*

This is the code that I currently have in my main class:

```
    String token = tokengenerator.generateQR(url, location);
    tokens.add(token);
    System.out.println(token);

    try {


    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
    System.out.println("Connected");
    Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate(token);
    System.out.println("Uploaded");
    }catch (SQLException e){
    System.err.println(e);
    }
```

and this is how I create my token

```
public static String generateQR(String url, String location) throws Exception {
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    uuid = uuid.replaceAll("-", "");         
    String scan= url + uuid;       
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(scan).to(ImageType.PNG).stream();
    File f = new File (location);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fos.write(out.toByteArray());
    fos.flush();        
 return uuid;        
}
```

I am unsure why it does not work and would like to upload a string to the database. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the query its running?

Comment: `stmt.executeUpdate` should be passed an SQL statement. The `token` you send looks like some long code, and not valid SQL. What kind of SQL update do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your `generateQR` function returns `uuid` which is not an sql statement. This returned value goest to the `token` variable which will be later trying to be executed.

Comment: what statement do I need in order to send the string to the sql database?

Comment: An sql statement should be. If you want to insert the token, it could be something  like: insert into yourtable (columname) values ('token')

Comment: I suggest you to first try the statement in mysql, then put the statement together in your java program and you can check with your println whether the statement looks good.

Comment: How can I try the statement in mysql?

Comment: With the mysql client program, or mysql workbench. I think you should learn at least very basic mysql knowledge. And there are good tutorials for that, don't ask here that "How can I try the statement in mysql", because SO is not a training service.